# AWS allow policy to create tags for instances on a particular VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-policy

I want to be able to apply tags only to instances running in EC2 on a particular VPC (vpc-11111111).
I tried to use the policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EC2TagNonresourceSpecificActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:<myRegion>:<myCustomerId>:vpc/vpc-11111111"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

but the user with this policy cannot modify the tags unless I remove the condition.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags do not support conditions, according to Amazon docs and support.

This is a long standing feature request for several years!

Comment: You can increase the quality and validity of your answer by [linking the source](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if given some particular AWS user rights, the Tag rights is inside the policies.
Mistake in your new policies will overwrite those default access. You should try it out using AWS policy simulator.

Try add a principal and try it out.

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<myCustomerId>:user/*"
}
```